# How to alternate animate polyline points?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, polyline

I have managed to get animations working with polyline points, but the can't manage to "reverse" the animation so that it wouldn't be jumping back to the beginning, but instead would animate from end to beginning (example: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bGyoz) as it's animated from beginning to end.
The points I'm using are generated in JS and then injected to HTML.

Current code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgzaBR

```css
 polyline {
        stroke-width: 1;
        stroke: black;
        fill: none;
        animation-direction: alternate;
    }
```

```html
<svg>
        <polyline>
            <animate
                attributeName="points"
                dur="5s"
                from="0,17 167,-20 350,39 511,-20 757,27 891,-35 1011,11 1206,-21 1342,35 1460,-26 1566,26 1797,-32 1932,36 2161,-10 2360,15 2587,-19 2832,13 3031,-18 3197,11 3318,-31 3543,32 3655,-10 3779,31 3882,-17 4065,20 4271,-24 4416,29 4572,-26 4804,27 4983,-27 5093,24 5272,-28 5389,31 5563,-26 5766,33 5929,-15 6052,38 6282,-31 6510,15 6682,-13 6907,29 7106,-22 7282,17 7467,-31 7580,20 7763,-16 7918,18 8098,-11 8339,15 8564,-32"
                to="0,-45.6 107,39.6 278,-45.6 488,44.4 621,-28.8 761,18 975,-24 1100,18 1203,-42 1448,38.4 1563,-12 1809,32.4 1936,-16.8 2105,37.2 2299,-37.2 2450,40.8 2654,-44.4 2875,24 3034,-44.4 3273,45.6 3426,-21.6 3650,36 3792,-26.4 3988,37.2 4088,-30 4232,44.4 4444,-18 4570,15.6 4755,-22.8 4870,43.2 5077,-28.8 5231,42 5431,-15.6 5546,36 5753,-12 5860,39.6 6101,-31.2 6230,31.2 6469,-44.4 6589,37.2 6745,-26.4 6896,34.8 7039,-45.6 7152,21.6 7382,-21.6 7568,13.2 7718,-12 7949,16.8 8058,-36 8178,20.4 "
                repeatCount="indefinite"
             ></animate>
        </polyline>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `from` and `to` you may use the `values` attribute. The value for the `values` attribute is a semicolon separated list of values. In this case use `from;to;from` like so:

```css
svg {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

polyline {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

animate {
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <polyline>
    <animate
             attributeName="points"
             dur="5s"
             values="0,17 167,-20 350,39 511,-20 757,27 891,-35 1011,11 1206,-21 1342,35 1460,-26 1566,26 1797,-32 1932,36 2161,-10 2360,15 2587,-19 2832,13 3031,-18 3197,11 3318,-31 3543,32 3655,-10 3779,31 3882,-17 4065,20 4271,-24 4416,29 4572,-26 4804,27 4983,-27 5093,24 5272,-28 5389,31 5563,-26 5766,33 5929,-15 6052,38 6282,-31 6510,15 6682,-13 6907,29 7106,-22 7282,17 7467,-31 7580,20 7763,-16 7918,18 8098,-11 8339,15 8564,-32;
                     0,-45.6 107,39.6 278,-45.6 488,44.4 621,-28.8 761,18 975,-24 1100,18 1203,-42 1448,38.4 1563,-12 1809,32.4 1936,-16.8 2105,37.2 2299,-37.2 2450,40.8 2654,-44.4 2875,24 3034,-44.4 3273,45.6 3426,-21.6 3650,36 3792,-26.4 3988,37.2 4088,-30 4232,44.4 4444,-18 4570,15.6 4755,-22.8 4870,43.2 5077,-28.8 5231,42 5431,-15.6 5546,36 5753,-12 5860,39.6 6101,-31.2 6230,31.2 6469,-44.4 6589,37.2 6745,-26.4 6896,34.8 7039,-45.6 7152,21.6 7382,-21.6 7568,13.2 7718,-12 7949,16.8 8058,-36 8178,20.4;
                     0,17 167,-20 350,39 511,-20 757,27 891,-35 1011,11 1206,-21 1342,35 1460,-26 1566,26 1797,-32 1932,36 2161,-10 2360,15 2587,-19 2832,13 3031,-18 3197,11 3318,-31 3543,32 3655,-10 3779,31 3882,-17 4065,20 4271,-24 4416,29 4572,-26 4804,27 4983,-27 5093,24 5272,-28 5389,31 5563,-26 5766,33 5929,-15 6052,38 6282,-31 6510,15 6682,-13 6907,29 7106,-22 7282,17 7467,-31 7580,20 7763,-16 7918,18 8098,-11 8339,15 8564,-32"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             ></animate>
  </polyline>
</svg>
```